# Why am I getting a string instead of a dictionary while reading a csv file in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a dictionary in a CSV file using this:

```
self.idSelf += 1
self.tweet["tweet"] = tweetText
self.tweet["id"] = id
self.tweet["sequence"] = self.idSelf
self.tweet["created_at"] = created_at
with open('#KXIPvMI-2018-05-04.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
     a = [self.tweet]
     print a[0]['tweet']
     writer.writerow([self.tweet])
```

While reading this file, I get a list of length = 1. I get the whole dictionary that I saved by writing `row = info[0]`. But when I get the `type(row)`, it is `str` and not the dictionary. Why is that and how can I get the dictionary?

Comment: To write a dictionary, you should use `csv.DictWriter`.

Comment: Okay. And what would be the appropriate and pythonic way for that?
Could you please post an answer with the snippet?

Comment: The answer is in the `csv.DictWriter` documentation.

Comment: @DyZ 
I am using DictWriter: `writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, self.fieldnames=fieldnames)`  but I am getting an error: 
`writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldNames = self.fieldNames)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: The error is likely coming from somewhere else. Look at the "official" example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: I have updated my answer to use DictWriter and DictReader, please see if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using csv.DictReader and csv.DictWriter, look at the sample code

```
import csv

di = {}
di["id"] = 1
di["val"] = "val"

with open("test.csv","a") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file,di.keys())
    writer.writerow(di)

with open("test.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,di.keys())
    for row in reader:
        print row["id"]
```

Comment: Using eval is not a good idea. Read about its potential threats. Instead you should use csv.DictReader